# Find all permutation and return result as List<string>

Tags: c#

I have following code written in c#.In which I am printing permutation of string.

```
void Main()
{
    RecPermute("", "abc");

}



void RecPermute(string soFar, string rest) {
    if (rest == "") {
        soFar.Dump();
    } else {
        for(int i=0; i<rest.Length; i++) {
            string next = soFar + rest[i];
            string remaining = rest.Substring(0, i) + rest.Substring(i+1);
            RecPermute(next, remaining);
    }
    }
}
```

Now I  change the signature of method as below.

```
List<string> RecPermute(string soFar, string rest)
```

and change the code

```
List<string> RecPermute(string soFar, string rest) {
List<string> result=new List<string>();
    if (rest == "") {
        //soFar.Dump();
        result.Add(soFar);
    } else {
        for(int i=0; i<rest.Length; i++) {
            string next = soFar + rest[i];
            string remaining = rest.Substring(0, i) + rest.Substring(i+1);
            RecPermute(next, remaining);
    }
    }
    return result;
}
```

The problem is that I am not getting any result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `List<string> result=new List<string>();` as local variable. This is what you want

```
List<string> result=new List<string>(); // NOT LOCAL!!!
List<string> RecPermute(string soFar, string rest) {

    if (rest == "") {
        //soFar.Dump();
        result.Add(soFar);
    } else {
        for(int i=0; i<rest.Length; i++) {
            string next = soFar + rest[i];
            string remaining = rest.Substring(0, i) + rest.Substring(i+1);
            RecPermute(next, remaining);
    }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Please, not that using a class level variable to store the result is most likely a bad idea.  I used this only as an example to point out that when result is local - it does not get populated with data.

Read the comments for this answer - there are different solutions for this problem, my personal favorite is [to use a parameter](http://dotnetfiddle.net/IaEfse):

```
    private List<string> RecPermute(string soFar, string rest, List<string> tmp = null)
    {
        if (tmp == null) tmp = new List<string>();
        if (rest == "")
        {
            //soFar.Dump();
            tmp.Add(soFar);
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < rest.Length; i++)
            {
                string next = soFar + rest[i];
                string remaining = rest.Substring(0, i) + rest.Substring(i + 1);
                RecPermute(next, remaining, tmp);
            }
        }
        return tmp;
    }
```

Comment: or change to `result.AddRange(RecPermute(next, remaining));`

Comment: @Grundy Your solution also works (http://dotnetfiddle.net/w0AqFN), but in this case a lot of temporary lists are created. If this is supposed to be static implementation - a new parameter can be added - this is still cheaper in terms of memory than creating several lists (like this - http://dotnetfiddle.net/IaEfse)

Comment: Using a global variable as a temporary variable for a function result is bad. This function should be rewritten to be recursive. So we should return something from the `else` block too. Then we won't need a global variable. I wanted to do it, but I couldn't do it right away, and unfortunately, I don't have time for it now :(

Comment: @FreeNickname Why? If you have an class with the logic and getting permutations is only one step of the algorithm - getting a private field to contain the result is exactly what you need to do! This will remove the pressure from passing parameters to all the methods that implement algorithm's steps.

Comment: @DarkWalker:After making changes code is working fine.I have one question what is general rule for handling this thing in recursion

Comment: @user2893534 There is no general rule. It depends on what you need - easy to understand code (for junior developers), thread-safety (is there a change something will try to access result before it is ready), performance (are you doing in with 5 elements or 5000 elements). Based on these criteria you choose different implementations (http://dotnetfiddle.net/IaEfse - this one is the most thread-safe, easy and fast at the same time I can think of).

Comment: @DarkWalker, well, for instance, what will happen if you run the function several times? You never reinitialize `result`. Then, why would you need a function's temporary variable in a global scope? What if, for instance, someone modifies this list from another thread while the function is running? Then, after calling the function, you'll have to assign this list to null manually, otherwise it will remain in memory. This is what comes to mind in the first place.

Comment: @FreeNickname And what if you have a console application with single thread? We simply do not have enough information to make a decision about good or bad here (see my previous comment about 'generic rule').

Comment: @DarkWalker I'm agree, there are exceptions from any rule. But in general it is a bad practice. That's why it is an exception. Now it sounds like a general solution: 'if you have a problem because of a local variable, make it global'. A novice programmer might follow this 'advice'. I'm glad that your answer helped, and I'm ready to remove the down vote if you add a short note to the answer, saying that using global variables this way is more likely an exception.

Comment: @FreeNickname Yeah, this is a good idea to mention it in original answer

Comment: @DarkWalker, here you go :)